# I need to call the setLocation function when pressed

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

I need to call the setLocation function when pressed. I made a form with a post method, I call a click test and nothing happens. What's the matter, tell me please. And another question: If there are a lot of such forms with the post method, the code should change? Do not throw stones, I'm a newbie in Php. Thank you in advance

Game.php

```
<?php
require "php/set_locations.php";
if(isset($_POST['location_button_1'])){
setLocation(4);
}
?>
<html>
<head><title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/GameStyle.css">
    
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="main_container">
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="body_container">
            <form method="post">
        <div class="left_menu_container">
            <div class="left_menu_main_div">
                <a class="left_menu_button">
                <span class="left_menu_span"></span>
                </a>
                <nav class="left_menu_nav">
                    <a href="#" class="left_menu_link">Инвентарь</a>
                    <a href="#" class="left_menu_link">Персонаж</a>    
                    <a href="#" class="left_menu_link">Ремесло</a>    
                    <a href="#" class="left_menu_link">Охота</a>    
                </nav>
                <div class="left_menu_close_container"></div>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Left_menu.js"></script>
            </div>
        </div>
                </form>
            <div class="main_image_container">
                <div class="image_container">
                    <div class="img_container">
                        <?php 
                        //$locationName = R::load('locationsdb', 1);
                        //echo '<img class="image_location" src="'.$locationName->location_image.'">'
                        
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="location_buttons_container">
                <div class="buttons_container">
                    
                    <ul class="buttons_menu">
                        <li>Локации</li>
                        <li ><span name="location_button_1">Главные ворота</span><em>3 сек.</em></li>
                        <li><span>Торговый квартал</span><em>2 сек</em></li>
                        <li><span>Замок</span><em>5 сек</em></li>
                        <li><span>Гильдия</span><em>4 сек</em></li>
                    </ul>
                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer_container">
            <div class="left_footer_block"></div>
            <div class="textarea_container">
            <textarea class="main_textArea" readonly></textarea>
                <div class="input_and_button_container">
                    <input class="input_for_main_textArea">
                    <div class="button_container">
                        <button class="set_text_button" ></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="onlinelist_container">
                <div class="online_list">
                    <ul class="online_list_ul">
                        <li><span>Герои в локации</span><em></em></li>
                        <li><span>IIITUKATUPKA</span><em>8</em></li>
                        <li><span>Tataliec</span><em>7</em></li>
                        <li><span>Nekita2012</span><em>6</em></li>
                        <li><span>Brion</span><em>5</em></li>
                        <li><span>Joken</span><em>4</em></li>
                        <li><span>Golden</span><em>5</em></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

setLocation.php:

```
<?php

require "php/include_db.php";
function setLocation($url_image){
   $locationName = R::load('locationsdb', $url_image);
    echo '<img class="image_location" src="'.$locationName->location_image.'">';
}
?>
```

Comment: What makes you think a span is sent to the server? Make it a submit button. There is no name attribute on a span `<input name="location_button_1" value="Главные ворота" />`

Comment: Is it possible to do this to any element, and span too?

Comment: Can this be done and how?

Comment: You can make a submit button with any name and any value but it has to be a submit button. Alternatively you can AJAX your values on click of a span, but then you need JavaScript